# ffprobe json output not working in exec, but works in CMD

Tags: php, json, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I've installed ffmpeg on my windows 2008 server.

I use this string in CMD and i get what i want to get in my

PHP file:

```
 ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "C:\wamp\www\uploads\fc30e528b500b26a391ed4f5ed484310.mp4"
```

This is my PHP function i found on another stackoverflow question, it had great feedback so i tested it.

```
$file_name = 'fc30e528b500b26a391ed4f5ed484310';
$file_ext = 'mp4';
$ffprobe = 'C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe';
$videoFile = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\uploads\\'.$file_name.'.'.$file_ext;

$cmd = shell_exec($ffprobe .' ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "'.$videoFile.'"');
$parsed = json_decode($cmd, true);
print_r($parsed);
```

What is get back is nothing. I also tried using the same function i used with ffmpeg(which i got working for ffmpeg).

```
$cmd = $ffprobe.' ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "'.$videoFile.'" 2>&1';
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

This also brings back nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Removed ffprobe after including the .exe fixed the problem:

```
$file_name = 'fc30e528b500b26a391ed4f5ed484310';
$file_ext = 'mp4';
$ffprobe = 'C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe';
$videoFile = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\uploads\\'.$file_name.'.'.$file_ext;
$cmd = shell_exec($ffprobe .' -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "'.$videoFile.'"');
$parsed = json_decode($cmd, true);
print_r($parsed);
```